# Linked-list entering node at end each time while get input from user but something went wrong with any method

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

While trying to append node at the end of the linked list for each input given by user, there is something wrong with this code. I'm not getting it why this is happening? Could someone please point out what the problem is? If any one knows, please suggest me something to fix this bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//structure with two fields 
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

};
// data type definition 
typedef struct node node;
//pointer to node which initially set to NULL
node *head=NULL;

//fucntion create and display
void create(int num);
void display();


main()
{
    int n,i,num;

    printf("enter the no of nodes : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        printf("enter the data : ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        create(num);

    }
    display();
}
```

> //function create

```
void create(int num)
{
    printf("\n");
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        node *temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;


    }

    else
    {
        node *temp1=head;
        while(temp1!=NULL)
        {
            temp1=temp1->next;

        }

        node *ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        ptr->data=num;
        ptr->next=temp1->next;
        temp1->next=ptr;


    }

}
```

> //function display()

```
void display()
{
    node *temp;
    temp=head;

    printf("list is : ");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;

    }

}
```

Comment: in create(int num) function, your while loop makes the pointer temp1 land on NULL (end of the list). There after, temp1->next=ptr; causes error, because you are trying to access location NULL

Answer (score 0):

This should help you!

```
void create(int num)
{
    printf("\n");
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        node *temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;


    }

    else
    {
        node *temp1=head;
        //Modified the condition to traverse till the last node, not the end of it
        while(temp1->next != NULL)
        {
            temp1=temp1->next;

        }

        node *ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        ptr->data=num;
        ptr->next=temp1->next;
        temp1->next=ptr;


    }

}
```

(Note: there might be other issues in the program, I have not run it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this part of the `create` function

```
node *temp1=head;
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
  temp1=temp1->next;
}

node *ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

ptr->data=num;
ptr->next=temp1->next;
temp1->next=ptr;
```

And it seems like you iterate over the list until you reach the end. At which point `temp1 == NULL`. But then you try to access `temp1->next` which should be an unaccessible memory (remember that you have just set it to `NULL` in the previous `while-loop`.

A debugger can help you with this situations (or even printing some information around). A widely used debugger is **gdb**.

*(Note: there might be other issues in the program, I have not run it)*